# Override resize behavior of winform window

Tags: c#, winforms, forms, resize, splitcontainer

I have a winform window. When I change the size of the screen, the screen immediately increases or decreases.

I would prefer the Resize behavior of the window will be like **Split Container**, as long as I drag the mouse I see only line that marks what will be the window size, and only in leaving the Resize operation will be made.

I saw several examples that show that by hiding the frame of the window, and then by clicking on the window itself paint frame.

I want that by clicking on the **frame** of the window(I don't want to hide the frame) and **not** on the window.

Is there any way to do this? (May override the behavior of the Resize in any way).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that you can't find any solution on the Internet. However I've tried a demo for this and it works **pretty** well.

In `winforms` and many other UI technologies, **you can't render something outside the window itself**. To get the effect we want, we have to render some **indicative border** outside or inside the window depending on how user resizes it. So looks like we're stuck?

BUT there is a kind of technique to do that (I call it layer technique). We need a transparent, non-focused layer to render the indicative border. This layer will have its `Size` and `Location` synchronized with the `Size` and `Location` (with just a little offset) of the main window. The layer will also be `invisible` by default and only shows when user resizes and hides when ending resizing.

That's pretty OK with the technique I mentioned. However how to **prevent/discard the default resizing** when user resizes the window? It's luckily that `Win32` supports 2 messages for this to be done easily:

- [WM_RESIZING](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632647%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) : is sent to the window when user starts and keeps resizing. The `LParam` holds the `RECT` structure of the current window when resizing. We read this info to render the indicative border correctly. Then we need to modify this `RECT` to the current `Bounds` of the window to discard the default resizing effect (the size and location are changed immediately).
- [WM_EXITSIZEMOVE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632623%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) : is sent to the window when the resizing or moving ends. We need to catch this message to assign the `Size` and `Location` of the window based on the `Size` and `Location` of the transparent layer and of course hide the layer then.

Now the problem is totally **solvable**. Here is the demo code I've made. Note that there is a very nasty unsolvable and incomprehensible bug here, it happens when you resize the `Top-Left` corner, the `Size` is updated correctly after releasing mouse but the `Location` is set with an offset. I've debugging but no luck. At some point the `Top` and `Left` jumps to unexpected values for **no clear reason**. **However**, resizing by all the sides (left, top, right, bottom) and other corners is OK. In fact, resizing by the `Top-Left corner` is hardly done by user so this solution is acceptable, I think.

```
//Must add using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
public partial class Form1 : Form
{        
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        //Sizing border initialization
        SizingBorderWidth = 3;
        SizingBorderStyle = DashStyle.Custom;
        SizingBorderColor = Color.Orange;
        //layer initialization
        layer.Owner = this;//especially this one.
        layer.Width = Width + SizingBorderWidth * 2;
        layer.Height = Height + SizingBorderWidth * 2;                         
        //Paint the border when sizing
        layer.Paint += (s, e) => {
            using (Pen p = new Pen(SizingBorderColor) { Width = SizingBorderWidth }) {
                if (Use3DSizingBorder) {
                    ControlPaint.DrawBorder3D(e.Graphics, sizingRect.Left, sizingRect.Top, sizingRect.Width, sizingRect.Height, Border3DStyle.Bump, Border3DSide.All);
                }
                else {
                    p.DashStyle = SizingBorderStyle;
                    p.LineJoin = LineJoin.Round;
                    if(p.DashStyle == DashStyle.Custom)
                       p.DashPattern = new float[] { 8f, 1f, 1f, 1f };//length of each dash from right to left
                    e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(p, sizingRect);
                }
            }
        };
        //Bind the Location of the main form and the layer form together
        LocationChanged += (s, e) => {
            Point p = Location;
            p.Offset(-SizingBorderWidth, -SizingBorderWidth);
            layer.Location = p;
        };
        //Set the intial Location of layer
        Load += (s, e) =>{                
            Point p = Location;
            p.Offset(-SizingBorderWidth, -SizingBorderWidth);
            layer.Location = p;
        };            
    }
    //Set this to true to use 3D indicative/preview border
    public bool Use3DSizingBorder { get; set; }
    //Change the indicative/preview border thickness
    public int SizingBorderWidth { get; set; }
    //Change the indicative/preview border style
    public DashStyle SizingBorderStyle { get; set; }
    //Change the indicative/preview border color
    public Color SizingBorderColor { get; set; }
    //hold the current sizing Rectangle
    Rectangle sizingRect;
    bool startSizing;
    bool suppressSizing;
    //This is a Win32 RECT struct (don't use Rectangle)
    public struct RECT
    {
        public int left, top, right, bottom;
    }
    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {
        if (m.Msg == 0x214&&!suppressSizing)//WM_SIZING = 0x214
        {                
            RECT rect = (RECT) m.GetLParam(typeof(RECT));
            int w = rect.right - rect.left;
            int h = rect.bottom - rect.top;
            sizingRect = new Rectangle() {X = SizingBorderWidth/2, Y = SizingBorderWidth/2, 
                                          Width = w, Height = h};
            layer.Left = rect.left-SizingBorderWidth;
            layer.Top = rect.top-SizingBorderWidth;
            layer.Width = w+2*SizingBorderWidth;
            layer.Height = h+2*SizingBorderWidth;
            if (!startSizing)
            {
                layer.Show();
                startSizing = true;
            }
            layer.Invalidate();
            //Keep the current position and size fixed
            rect.right = Right;
            rect.bottom = Bottom;
            rect.top = Top;
            rect.left = Left;
            //---------------------------
            Marshal.StructureToPtr(rect, m.LParam, true);
        }
        if (m.Msg == 0x232)//WM_EXITSIZEMOVE = 0x232
        {
            layer.Visible = false;
            BeginInvoke((Action)(() => {
                suppressSizing = true;
                Left = layer.Left + SizingBorderWidth;
                Top = layer.Top + SizingBorderWidth;
                Width = layer.Width - 2 * SizingBorderWidth;
                Height = layer.Height - SizingBorderWidth * 2;
                suppressSizing = false;
            }));
            startSizing = false;
        }
        base.WndProc(ref m);            
    }
    //Here is the layer I mentioned before.
    NoActivationForm layer = new NoActivationForm();
}    
public class NoActivationForm : Form {
    public NoActivationForm() {
        //The following initialization is very important
        TransparencyKey = BackColor;
        FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
        ShowInTaskbar = false;
        StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual;            
        //----------------------------------------------                          
    }
    protected override bool ShowWithoutActivation {
        get { return true; }
    }
}
```

Some screen shots:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

**EDIT:** (This edit was suggested by `Hodaya Shalom`, the OP (weird :)

I found a solution to the left corner problem :

before the BeginInvoke I save the variables and in the invoke I put the local variable:

```
int _top = layer.Top + SizingBorderWidth;
int _left = layer.Left + SizingBorderWidth;
int _width = layer.Width - 2 * SizingBorderWidth;
int _height = layer.Height - SizingBorderWidth * 2;
BeginInvoke((Action)(() => {
    suppressSizing = true;
    Left = _left;
    Top = _top;
    Width =_width;
    Height =_height;
    suppressSizing = false;
}));
```

Comment: @HodayaShalom thanks for posting the suggestion. It really works. Well, however I don't think it's because of using `BeginInvoke`, I used `BeginInvoke` because I think we need to perform the window update as soon as possible. We don't need to use `BeginInvoke`, if that's because of `BeginInvoke`, removing `BeginInvoke` would have solved the problem, but it couldn't. I think assigning the `Left` and `Top` **directly** may cause the problem, so saving the values into some local variables solve it. At least thanks to you I know of this weird behavior and will apply it in the same situations.